# How to render child components out of its fixed position parent?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-position, fixed

I would like to render child component outside of its fixed-positioned parent div. But, the child component is always rendered within its fixed-position parent component. Taking the codes and image as an example, how to render 'Test 2' at the same position as the 'Test 1' instead of within its fixed-positioned div? I would like to render it based on browser viewport but not its fixed parent div. Thanks in advance!

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

function Testing() {
    const [isCLicked, setIsCLicked] = useState(false)
    return (
        <div style={{
            position:'relative',
            width:'100vw',
            height:'100vh',
            backgroundColor:'lightblue',
        }}>
            <p style={{
                position:'absolute',
                top:'10%',
                left:'10%',
                backgroundColor:'black',
                color:'white'
            }}>Test 1</p>

            <div style={{
                position:'fixed',
                top:0,
                left:'50%',
                height:'100vh',
                width:'10vw',
                backgroundColor:'green'
            }}>
                <button onClick={()=>setIsCLicked(true)}>create new text box</button>
                {isCLicked && 
                    <p style={{
                        position:'absolute',
                        top:'10%',
                        left:'10%',
                        backgroundColor:'black',
                        color:'white'
                    }}>Test 2</p>
                }
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Testing
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't move your child out of your parent if this parent has a fixed or relative position. You will have to take your child out of your parent, putting it on the same level, at least.

Now, if your child depend on some data your parent have, well you can either use `prop drilling` to send these datas to their common parent. This way you will be able to share data between those two.

If there is multiple level between your child and parent that need to share data, then take the child out of the parent (this is mandatory, no matter the idea you have) and use a context Api or a state management to share datas.

The best idea is to **find a way not to use fixed position**, since your code does not seems to be complicated, it could be refactored to achieve what you want.